# Turn left, right, accelerate or decelerate with Python turtle

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

I am using turtle trying to move my Sprite and let it turn left or right or accelerate or decelerate. But my coding does not work. It only moves towards one direction and then disappears on the screen. Not sure where I did wrong.

```
import turtle
turtle.fd(0)
turtle.speed(0)
turtle.bgcolor("black")
turtle.hideturtle()
turtle.setundobuffer(1)
turtle.tracer(1)


class Sprite(turtle.Turtle):
    def __init__(self, spriteshape, color, startx, starty):
        turtle.Turtle.__init__(self, shape=spriteshape)
        self.speed(0)
        self.penup()
        self.color(color)
        self.fd(0)
        self.goto(startx, starty)
        self.speed = 1

    def move(self):
        self.fd(self.speed)


class Player(Sprite):
    def __init__(self, spriteshape, color, startx, starty):
        Sprite.__init__(self, spriteshape, color, startx, starty)
        self.speed = 4
        self.lives = 3

    def turn_left(self):
        self.lt(45)

    def turn_right(self):
        self.rt(45)

    def accelerate(self):
        self.speed += 1

    def decelerate(self):
        self.speed -= 1


# Create my sprite
player = Player("triangle", "white", 0, 0)
turtle.onkey(player.turn_left, "Left")
turtle.onkey(player.turn_right, "Right")
turtle.onkey(player.accelerate, "Up")
turtle.onkey(player.decelerate, "Down")
turtle.listen()

# Main game loop
while True:
    player.move()
```

Answer (score 3):

Your code basically seems to work -- it just starts out so fast it's hard to get control of it before it runs off the screen.  The major problem I see with the code is that you both redefined `turtle.speed` while trying to use both it's original and new definition.  You should come up with a different name for your 'speed' instance variable.

The next problem is that you use `while True:` which has no place in an event-driven world like turtle.  You should use a timer event instead.  The following rework addresses both of the above issues and tweaks some other details:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

class Sprite(Turtle):
    def __init__(self, spriteshape, color, startx, starty):
        super().__init__(shape=spriteshape)
        self.my_speed = 1

        self.speed('fastest')
        self.color(color)
        self.penup()
        self.goto(startx, starty)

    def move(self):
        self.forward(self.my_speed)

class Player(Sprite):
    def __init__(self, spriteshape, color, startx, starty):
        super().__init__(spriteshape, color, startx, starty)
        self.my_speed = 4

    def turn_left(self):
        self.left(45)

    def turn_right(self):
        self.right(45)

    def accelerate(self):
        self.my_speed += 1

    def decelerate(self):
        self.my_speed -= 1

# Main game loop
def run():
    player.move()
    screen.ontimer(run, 50)

screen = Screen()
screen.bgcolor("black")

# Create my sprite
player = Player("triangle", "white", 0, 0)

screen.onkey(player.turn_left, "Left")
screen.onkey(player.turn_right, "Right")
screen.onkey(player.accelerate, "Up")
screen.onkey(player.decelerate, "Down")
screen.listen()

run()

screen.mainloop()
```